# Wordpress show posts based on post type not working

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm working on my website and stuck on something. For some reason I can't get the posts from the specific custom post type, only from the standard post type.

Even if I set post_type to the specific post type.
What am I doing wrong?

I thought this would be enough to display the post.

The shortcode I use is based on the post id:

```
[bookmaker p=20]
[bookmaker p=54]
[bookmaker p=38]
[bookmaker p=50]
```

My funtion:

```
add_shortcode('bookmaker', 'bookmaker_shortcode_query');

function bookmaker_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
  extract(shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '1',
   'post_type' => 'Bookmakers',
   'caller_get_posts' => 1)
   , $atts));



  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($atts);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
            $out = '        <div class="bookmaker">
        <div class="bookmakerinner">



            <div class="afbeeldingbm">
            <div class="afbeeldingbminner">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'claimlink', true).'">
                '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightbm">

            <h4>'.get_the_title() .'</h4>

            <div class="stars">
                <p><img src="https://bonusbookmakers.nl/wp-content/themes/Parbosnack/stars/'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stars', true).'.png"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="voorwaarden">
                <strong class="bolder">Voorwaarden:</strong> '.get_the_content().'
            </div>

            <div class="maxeur">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Max:</strong> &euro;'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'maxeur', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="maxbonus">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Bonus:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'maxbonus', true).'%</p>
            </div>

            <div class="odds">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Odds:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'odds', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="lang">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Taal:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'taal', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="priceclaimrow"> 

            <div class="betaalmethodes">
                <p>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'betaalmethodes', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="visitwebsite">
                <p><a target="_blank" class="knpbezoeksite" href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'claimlink', true).'">Bonus claimen</a></p>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

                ';
            $out .='</div>';
    endwhile;
  else
    return; // no posts found

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

Comment: Bookmakers dont seem to be an post type. This is not sanitized (maybe bookmaker?)

Comment: you should try 'post_type' => 'bookmakers',

Comment: According to your code, the `p` being declared in your shortcode doesn't do anything.

Comment: Just print_r the $atts just before new WP_Query($atts); you can see that it only have the value of p, so shortcode_atts is called but you didnt assigned its retuned value to atts instead you have extracted it, remove extract, save the array returned by shortcode_atts to another variable say $args then use new WP_Query($args); (plz avoid using capital letters in custum post types see answer i have posted)

Comment: @Christiaan Thankz friend for accepting the answer, plz give an upvote tooo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your code plz check now its working ,

```
add_shortcode('bookmaker', 'bookmaker_shortcode_query');

function bookmaker_shortcode_query($atts, $content){
  $args = shortcode_atts(array( // a few default values
   'posts_per_page' => '1',
   'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_type',
   'p' => '1',
   'caller_get_posts' => 1)
   , $atts);


  global $post;

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);
  $output = '';
    if ($posts->have_posts())
        while ($posts->have_posts()):
            $posts->the_post();
            $out = '        <div class="bookmaker">
        <div class="bookmakerinner">



            <div class="afbeeldingbm">
            <div class="afbeeldingbminner">
                <a target="_blank" href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'claimlink', true).'">
                '.get_the_post_thumbnail().'
                </a>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="rightbm">

            <h4>'.get_the_title() .'</h4>

            <div class="stars">
                <p><img src="https://bonusbookmakers.nl/wp-content/themes/Parbosnack/stars/'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'stars', true).'.png"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="voorwaarden">
                <strong class="bolder">Voorwaarden:</strong> '.get_the_content().'
            </div>

            <div class="maxeur">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Max:</strong> &euro;'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'maxeur', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="maxbonus">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Bonus:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'maxbonus', true).'%</p>
            </div>

            <div class="odds">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Odds:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'odds', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="lang">
                <p><strong class="bolder">Taal:</strong> '.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'taal', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="priceclaimrow"> 

            <div class="betaalmethodes">
                <p>'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'betaalmethodes', true).'</p>
            </div>

            <div class="visitwebsite">
                <p><a target="_blank" class="knpbezoeksite" href="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'claimlink', true).'">Bonus claimen</a></p>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>

        </div>

                ';
            $out .='</div>';
    endwhile;
  else
    return; // no posts found

  wp_reset_query();
  return html_entity_decode($out);
}
```

Comment: How? He asked for custom post type. He does not want to get post type page.

Comment: Dude that was just a demo code you can change page with any post type, or by using the shortcode [bookmaker p=50 post_type="your_post_type"], anyway I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Custom post type **cannot** have capital letters

> $post_type
>
> **max. 20 characters, cannot contain capital letters or spaces**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type